# Commas in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to know what effect a comma has on a propositional statement.

For example:

> $\{\neg p, p \vee q \} \vDash q$

Does this bit $\{\neg p, p \vee q \}$  mean just $q$?

Thanks.

Comment: The comma is there to separate two items in a set.

Answer (score 4):

In your case the commas are being used to separate propositions (premises) in an argument. In your example, the premises $\neg p $ and $p\vee q$ result in $q$.

Comment: Okay so what do the brackets actually do? for example say I have                  ¬ (p ∧ ¬q}. Is this the same as ¬p ∧ q?

Comment: They are not necessary but can mean that you have a set of propositions called premises.

Comment: So ¬ (p ∧ ¬q} Is not the same as ¬p ∧ q? What affect does the negation outside of the bracket do? What affect does it have on the propositions onside the bracket?

Comment: It does not seem to make sense

Comment: Okay say for example what would be the truth table for this ¬ (p ∧ ¬q}?

Answer (score 3):

The comma is not part of any propositional formula. The *set* before the symbol $\models$ has two elements, both formulas:

- $\neg\, p$
- $p \lor q$

The statement $\{\neg\, p, p \lor q\} \vdash q$ means: $q$ follows from the two premises, in some particular deductive system. In LaTeX/MathJax, $\vdash$ is written as "\vdash". The symbol $\models$ means: $q$ is true in every interpretation where the premises are true. $\models$ is written as "\models" or "\vDash". Because of the Completeness Theorem for propositional logic, these two notions are identical.